# Show $\mathbb{F}_2$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

From the definition of a field, I believe there must exist an inverse for each element in the claimed field. So, in my case, $\mathbb{F}_2=\{0,1\}$ then how could one find an inverse for $0 \in \mathbb{F}_2$ under multiplication?

I remember in group theory, we usually omit $0$ when the binary operation is standard multiplication or anything similar, so to avoid situations like I am in now to arise; no inverse exists.(I believe the identity of multiplication here is $1$ since any element multiplied by $1$ is the element itself).

Do I just...ignore $0$? $0 \times 0=0 \times 1=0$ and no other elements exist in my claimed field, so no inverse exists for $0$ under multiplication.

Or have I understood the definition of a field wrongly? If so, can someone explain it to me?

Thank you

Comment: You have misunderstood the definition. Take another look at it.

Comment: What kind of elements need inverses?

Comment: Ah, okay, I went back to wikipedia and it says "OTHER THAN $0$" so i guess we ignore $0$ by definition...thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show $(F,+,\cdot)$ is a field, it is enough to show

1. $(F,+)$ is an abelian group
2. $(F\backslash \{0\}, \cdot)$ is an abelian group
3. $\cdot$ distributes over $+$ in the usual way (on both sides)